# I'm getting a stack overflow exception in C++ program

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, stack-overflow

I am getting a system.stackoverflowexception.

I think it is happening somewhere inside the `insert()` function.

```
void insert(char* word){
    int r1 = rand()%x;         // Here is where I suspect the problem starts
    int c1 = rand()%x;
    if(gameBoard[r1][c1]=="") {
        gameBoard[r1][c1] = word;
        insertWordCopy(word);
    } else 
        insert(word);
    }
```

Comment: It'd be helpful to cut your code down to the bare minimum to reproduce, or failing that, show which line is `81`.

Comment: Woa... just dumping your whole program and saying, "What's wrong?" won't work very well here.

Comment: Did you step into the code with a debugger?

Comment: "somewhere around line 81", and you expect us to start counting? You could at least paste line numbered code..

Comment: sorry it was not my intention to "dump" my code here, I was going to put just the line 81 chunk but since i'm not really sure where the problem is occurring i figured best bet was to put my whole program

Comment: Simplify your life and use `std::string`.  It behaves more like a string than an array of nul terminated characters.

Comment: This looks more like C than C++. try using std::string and std::vector instead of char* and C-style arrays. If you do that, your problem will probably disappear (see NPEs answer). It's better style and less error prone.

Answer (score 4):

The following is incorrect, since it compares the pointers:

```
if(gameBoard[r2][c2]=="") {
```

As a result, the code almost certainly always goes down the `else` branch, resulting in infinite recursion.